# Laravel 9 - Submitting a form to a route leads to /null and doesn't do anything

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm using soft deletes and trying to make a function to restore the deleted row. Really everything to do with submitting the form doesn't work, even deleting...

My  tags are within a forelse loop, maybe that's the cause??

Route is (this is above my resource route):

```
Route::post('/post/restore/{id}', [PostController::class, 'restore'])
    ->name('post.restore');
```

Controller is:

```
public function restore($id)
{
    dd($id);
}
```

Form/view is:

```
<form action="{{route('post.restore', $post->id)}}" method="POST">
@csrf

<button type="submit" class="dropdown-item popup" data-confirm="Would you like to restore?">Restore</button>
</form>
```

After submitting, it just takes me to:

*domainURL*/post/null

and gives a 404 error

Any advice?? I also tried it without the {id} at the end of the route, same results

Comment: What does `$post->id` in your view return? Do you actually get the id or is it `null`? And do you have a `post.show` route? Make sure the `post.restore` route is registered above the `post.show` route in your routes file

Comment: are you restoring after deleting or what action leads to losing the data?

Comment: @Remul Yeah $post->id does return the correct ID, it's within a forelse loop though - not sure if that would effect forms? I have the complete <form> tags within the forelse loop

Comment: @It'sVIN Sorry I forgot to mention I use soft deletes, I'm trying to restore the soft deleted row but for now I'm just trying to figure out why it's not even hitting my dd($id)

Comment: @Remul I use a resource for the index, show, update, etc. But I did list my post.restore above that

Comment: @JamesErikson please add the forelse loop code to your question

Comment: @JamesErikson please make sure $post(id) is available. its a resource and you are passing one that is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... my "would you like to restore?" javascript function was breaking the form. I was using javascript to popup a confirmation message before submitting and during that process it lost the ID

I got rid of that and it works fine

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong syntax for `route` function, instead of this:

```
route('post.restore', $post->id)
```

you should use it like this:

```
route('post.restore', ['id' => $post->id])
```

you can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) as well.